# aws_lb_target_group_attachment: attaching multiple instances to per target_group

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have multiple target_groups per NLB and I need to attach multiple instances to each target_group. The `target_id` being a string in `aws_lb_target_group_attachment` resource, I don't see any easy way to achieve that. This is what I'm doing atm:

#### vars.tf

```
variable "nlb_listeners" {
  default = [
    {
      protocol     = "TCP"
      target_port  = "80"
      health_port  = "1936"
    },
    {
      protocol     = "TCP"
      target_port  = "443"
      health_port  = "1936"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### instances .tf

```
// Get the instance ids of the NLB members  
data "aws_instances" "nlb_insts" {
  instance_tags = {
   Name = "${var.vpc_names[var.idx]}${var.inst_role}0*"
  }
  instance_state_names = ["running", "stopped"]
}

// EC2 instances
resource "aws_instance" "insts" {
  count         = var.inst_count
  instance_type = var.inst_type
  .......
}
```

#### balancer.tf

```
// Creates the target-group
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "nlb_target_groups" {
  count                = length(var.nlb_listeners)
  name                 = "nlb-tgr-${lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "target_port")}"
  deregistration_delay = var.deregistration_delay
  port                 = lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "target_port")
  protocol             = lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "protocol")
  vpc_id               = var.vpc_ids[var.idx]

  health_check {
    port                = lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "health_port")
    protocol            = lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "protocol")
    interval            = var.health_check_interval
    unhealthy_threshold = var.unhealthy_threshold
    healthy_threshold   = var.healthy_threshold
  }
}

// Attach the target groups to the instance(s)
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tgr_attachment" {
  count            = length(var.nlb_listeners)
  target_group_arn = element(aws_lb_target_group.nlb_target_groups.*.arn, count.index)
  target_id        = [for sc in range(var.inst_count) : data.aws_instances.nlb_insts.ids[sc]]
  port             = lookup(var.nlb_listeners[count.index], "target_port")
}
```

so, I'm getting this error:

> Error: Incorrect attribute value type
>
> on ../../modules/elb/balencer.tf line 31, in resource
>   "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tgr_attachment": 31: target_id =
>   [for sc in range(2) : data.aws_instances.nlb_insts.ids[sc]]
>
> Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.

Anyone has any idea how do I achieve that?

Comment: any suggestion/comment from anyone?

Comment: Hey MacUsers, you have to create an attachment per Target Resource, you are passing a list while the "target_id" is expecting a single string.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lb_target_group_attachment#target_id

In order to achieve what you want you would need to create a structure that you can iterate over using a `for_each`. I could guide you through if you think this fits your scenario.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Im trying the same thing, but I cant use count and foreach in the same resource so I cant attach the instances to the each target groups unfortunately.

Comment: nope, I gave up and I started using ASG in the end to go around that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking at your code I would say this is the mistake that was giving you your error:

```
data.aws_instances.nlb_insts.ids[sc]
```

Should be:

```
data.aws_instances.nlb_insts[sc].ids
```

The index goes on the resource, then you get the ids from your resource, in your case you were trying to get all the ids of all the resources and then get the index of that, which is not the way to do it!